# MySQL-NT is crashing frequently

Tags: mysql

MySQL is crashing frequently and there is no error in the err log file.

The following error message was found in the event viewer:

> faulting application mysqld-nt.exe, version 0.0.0.0, faulting module mysqld-nt.exe, version 0.0.0.0 fault address 0X001176b8

- MySQL version - 5.0.24
- OS - Win2003 with 4GB Ram

Is there any problem with combination of MySQL 5.0.24 and Win2003?

Comment: Do you have a good reason for not patching MySQL to [5.0.92](http://downloads.mysql.com/archives.php?p=mysql-5.0)? (I'm assuming you can't upgrade)

Comment: +1, without knowing much, I would say upgrade to the highest version you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not with win2003 and MySQL.

Trend Micro Antivirus was running and was not allowing MySQL temp files to be created/writen.

I added an exception to the MySQL temp directory and from that time, the service has been running properly.

Answer (score 3):

I would upgrade away from MySQL 5.0 altogether.

Please note you are using mysqld-nt.exe

It has been a very long (probably over 1.5 yrs) since the NT-featured mysqld was distributed. The only benefit to using mysqld-nt was if you are using shared memory or named pipes, which were just nuances when MySQL 5.0 came out for Windows.

The MFC C++ runtime distributables have been updated several times over the years. If you have been running updates against Win2003, things are probably very different for mysqld-nt.exe now.

Before upgrading, try using mysqld.exe instead of mysqld-nt.exe. If you still get the same crashing behavior, switch out of MySQL 5.0 for Windows and go to MySQL 5.5 because [**MySQL Support for Windows 2003 went EndOfLife back in April of 2011**](http://www.mysql.com/support/eol-notice.html). I would also think about using a Windows 7 Server instead of Windows 2000/2003/NT.