# How to check/change MySQL named pipe settings?

Tags: mysql, windows, mysql-5

I'm having a hard time finding anything on this because I don't know what to call it.  But when you install MySQL it asks you if you want to allow connections to the database from other machines or not, and gives you an option to use named pipe.   Well, I want to check how a particular server is setup and change it.  How do you do that? I mean without reinstalling.

Comment: Named pipes only works with Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Windows, you need not worry about named pipes at all. Why ?

Years ago, MySQL for Windows had distributed three(3) different executables:

- `mysqld.exe`
- `mysqld-nt.exe`
- `mysqld-max-nt.exe`

The two executeables `mysqld-nt.exe` and `mysqld-max-nt.exe` used the named pipes protocol. This is briefly mentioned in [Chapter 23 Section 23.2 Page 353 Bulletpoint 3 of the Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672328127)

[image: MySQL 5.0 Certification Study Guide]

I have a 3-year-old post about this ([MySQL-NT is crashing frequently](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6217/mysql-nt-is-crashing-frequently/6227#6227))

Those NT-based mysqld executables are no longer being distributed. Even for `mysqld-nt`, `--enable-named-pipe` was not enabled by default. [The option is still available today for mysqld.exe](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_named_pipe).

Do yourself a favor and do not enable it since there is so little documentation on using this protocol. It was originally meant for Windows NT (Not There).

## YOUR ACTUAL QUESTION

You can run

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'named_pipe';
```

It will either say `ON` or `OFF`.

You can configure it by adding this to `my.ini` under the `[mysqld]` group header

```
[mysqld]
named-pipe
```

and restarting `mysqld.exe` by running (as Administrator)

```
C:\> net stop mysql
C:\> net start mysql
```

Comment: I must say, that I had the opposite experience, where TCP based version of the connector was causing problems and delays, while pipe-based version works excellent, fast, and with consistent read-write times

Answer (score 2):

This is something you set up when [starting](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_enable-named-pipe) the mysqld daemon (or service on Windows). You should (don't have Windows running) be able to see your startup options using the Task Manager (or failing that, use Process Explorer from [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653)).