# mysql.sock not generated when starting MySQL server using XAMPP

Tags: mysql

I have XAMPP installed, and I want to use mysql.sock file for my rails app.

Now, when I start the MySQL server (from xampp control panel), it starts, I see it's PID, I can access the mysql command line etc, but I can't find the mysql.sock file anywhere.

I'm running under Windows 7.

Any idea what might could have gone wrong?

EDIT:
Here's the error log, from mysql_error.log - this is what I see when i start MySQL from xampp control panel:

```
2015-07-16 13:51:27 4088 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-07-16 13:51:27 16f0 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2015-07-16 13:51:27 4088 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-07-16 13:51:27 4088 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-07-16 13:51:27 4088 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2015-07-16 13:51:27 4088 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-07-16 13:51:27 4088 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-07-16 13:51:27 4088 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-07-16 13:51:27 4088 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2015-07-16 13:51:27 4088 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-07-16 13:51:27 4088 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-07-16 13:51:27 4088 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 1665558 and 1665558 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 1666100 in the ib_logfiles!
2015-07-16 13:51:27 4088 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2015-07-16 13:51:27 4088 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2015-07-16 13:51:27 4088 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2015-07-16 13:51:27 4088 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
2015-07-16 13:51:27 4088 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
2015-07-16 13:51:28 4088 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-07-16 13:51:28 4088 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-07-16 13:51:28 4088 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.24 started; log sequence number 1666100
2015-07-16 13:51:28 4088 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2015-07-16 13:51:28 4088 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2015-07-16 13:51:28 4088 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2015-07-16 13:51:28 4088 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2015-07-16 13:51:28 4088 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2015-07-16 13:51:28 4088 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.24'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

Comment: Have you searched in the default locations? You could try specifying it manually when you start the daemon, i.e. "--socket=C:\...."

Comment: Yes, I searched the whole xampp folder, and whole C:\ partition.

How can I check the statuses of mysqld and mysql? P.S I updated the question with error log content. Maybe that can be of help.

Comment: I just took a look at my error.log (this is for Linux) - and at the very last line, where you have "socket: ''" - i.e. socket is blank, I have a filename - so something is wrong. In your my.ini, in both the [mysqld] and the [client] sections, specify a socket thus - socket = C:/www/tmp/mysql.sock (or wherever). This should do the trick for you.

Comment: Here's my my.ini:
http://pastebin.com/stxkX1TM

I have socket path specified? Can you compare it to your my.ini, is there something missing?

Answer (score 1):

I have **BAD NEWS** and **VERY BAD NEWS**

## BAD NEWS

[Connecting to MySQL via the socket file is a Unix-only protocol](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connecting.html#option_general_protocol)

> This option explicitly specifies a protocol to use for connecting to the server. It is useful when the other connection parameters normally would cause a protocol to be used other than the one you want. For example, connections on Unix to localhost are made using a Unix socket file by default:
>
> ```
> shell> mysql --host=localhost
> ```
>
> To force a TCP/IP connection to be used instead, specify a --protocol option:
>
> ```
> shell> mysql --host=localhost --protocol=TCP
> ```
>
> The following table shows the permissible --protocol option values and indicates the platforms on which each value may be used. The values are not case sensitive.
>
> ```
> --protocol Value   Connection Protocol                              Operating Systems
> TCP                TCP/IP connection to local or remote server      All
> SOCKET             Unix socket file connection to local server      Unix only
> PIPE               Named-pipe connection to local or remote server  Windows only
> MEMORY             Shared-memory connection to local server         Windows only
> ```

Therefore, MySQL for Windows does not create a socket file and you cannot connect with one.

[The closest protocol you want to use like a socket file is the named pipe](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connecting.html)

> On Windows, you can force a MySQL client to use a named-pipe connection by specifying the --pipe or --protocol=PIPE option, or by specifying . (period) as the host name. If named-pipe connections are not enabled, an error occurs. Use the [--socket](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connecting.html#option_general_socket) option to specify the name of the pipe if you do not want to use the default pipe name.

## VERY BAD NEWS

I have an old posts where I mentioned that certain builds of mysqld.exe supported named pipes but are no longer being distributed :

- `Oct 15, 2014` : [How to check/change MySQL named pipe settings?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/80283/how-to-check-change-mysql-named-pipe-settings/80286#80286)
- `Sep 27, 2011` : [MySQL-NT is crashing frequently](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6217/mysql-nt-is-crashing-frequently/6227#6227)

As I said in [How to check/change MySQL named pipe settings?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/80283/how-to-check-change-mysql-named-pipe-settings/80286#80286)

> Do yourself a favor and do not enable it since there is so little documentation on using this protocol. It was originally meant for Windows NT (Not There).

## SUGGESTION

Connect with TCP/IP instead of trying to work with named pipes

Comment: I had a suspicion that that was the case - even Googled for it, but found a my.ini suggestion instead. That'll teach me to properly research my input! Thanks for pointing that out.